# How do I representation percentage in evolutionary Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

Considering I have 4 chromosomes (gi, i=1 to 4}) to represent 4 percentages of different things so that the sum of 4 percentages are equal to 100. How Do I represent this efficiently?

I know that it is possible by: g1/(g1+g2+g3+g4). However, This is not efficient. Consider all gi=0.2 or all gi=0.1 will represent 25% in these two cases. It is possible to generate many cases where different genes present same percentage. Is there any other efficient way, where unique set of combination of genes present unique set of percentages.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think my question is not clear. Lets think I have x unit of something. I need to split x units into 4 different things. My genes are representation of percentages that how x unit is spited into 4 things.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing genes and chromosomes. A chromosome encodes a candidate solution to your problem. A gene is part of a chromosome.

Under this setting, why would you want that constraint on the **chromosomes**? it sounds like you want it on the **genes of a chromosome**.

In order to do this you can do a number of things: have each gene encode an integer in `[0, 100]`. If the genes do not add to `100` in the end, penalize the fitness of those chromosomes.

Another way, which might make crossover operators more natural to apply, is to have each gene store 100 bits. If `x` bits are set, that means the gene will encode `x%`.

Yet another way is to have the entire chromosome encode `100` set bits. Then each gene will hold a value `x`, which represents an interval. The number of set bits between two split points is the percentage associated to that gene. For example:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ... 100
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ... 1
|      |     | |    |
   g1    g2  g3  g4
```

This can be done by generating 5 random numbers `<= 100`, sorting them and taking the differences between them.

Comment: please check the last comments. Thanks for make me clear about gene and chromosome.

Answer (score 0):

One way to assign **X** units to **N** possibilities is to store **X * (N-1)** bits. Every unit is given **(N-1)** bits and if **k** of the **(N-1)** bits are set then the unit is assigned to **k**.

This is easy to work with as there are no invalid solutions and no penalties/repairs are necessary. This makes fitness evaluation, crossover and mutation easier to implement.

For example, the problem is to assign 5 units (X) to one of 4 (N) possibilities. Each individual is (4-1)x5=15 bits.

The bit string: 010 100 000 011 111 assigns the first 2 units to possibility 1 because both groups have 1 bit set. The third unit which has no bits set is assigned to 0. The fourth unit is assigned to 2 and the fifth to 3.

```
partition   units
0           1
1           2
2           1
3           1
```

Comment: Hi there, I had the idea. But the problem is sometimes it is possible that crossover creates invalid individuals. Where one individual may have (k+1) set bits and another one have (k-1) set bits.

Comment: Yes, If you apply one point crossover, child will be always valid. But I am considering 4 points crossover (as I have 4 units), where it is possible that child will be not valid.@rpattiso

Comment: I was off by one in my description, so I have updated the answer and added an example.